# Taking a screen shot of current web page and then converting it to pdf with ABCpdf

Tags: c#, abcpdf

Is it possible to take a screen shot of the current web page the user is one and then convert that screen shot to a pdf with ABCpdf? If so how? I've tried taking a screen shot as a bitmap and then converting that with ABCpdf but this compiler says that you "cannot convert bitmap to ABCpdf8.XImage" Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating small project to learn how to create PDF from an image, likely there is a image type (ipg/png?) that would work.

Next learn how to convert BMP to this type ([Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) is able to save to multiple formats).

At this point you have most pieces and should be able to string them together.

Additional step if you solution is ASP.Net: figure out if you want to take screenshot on client (need to run custom executable or ActiveX control on client side) or server in case of ASP.Net solution (need to find a way to render current page on server - plenty questions on this site).